# I got the error when I do 'truffle test' in Truffle tutorial that pet-shop-tutorial

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

I'm doing truffle tutorial the pet-shop-tutorial but when I typed `truffle test` in cmd, I got the error. Here is the error message.[image] 
I have no idea how I can fix it and where should I check.
Please help me and if you need to see some code or anything else, please let me know.

Comment: which truffle and solc version do you have, are you using Ganache=?

Comment: `before all hook` means that you have a problem in one of the `before` or `beforeEach` clauses in your test. Since you haven't posted your test, it is rather difficult to answer your question with more details. Please do that, and please post everything in plaintext (no links or images).